# Node.js "LearnYouNode" juggling async function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to javascript and node.js, so this might be basic javascript problem..

I'm solving this Juggling Async problem in LearnYouNode, but I don't know why my code isn't working.

my code:

```
const http = require('http');

var URLs = [process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]];
var strs = ["", "", ""];
var ctr = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    http.get(URLs[i], (response) => {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', (data) => {
            strs[i] += data;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            ctr++;
            if(ctr == 3){
                console.log(strs[0]);
                console.log(strs[1]);
                console.log(strs[2]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My code doesn't work, but this code does:

```
const http = require('http');

var URLs = [process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]];
var strs = ["", "", ""];
var ctr = 0;

function httpGet(i){
    http.get(URLs[i], (response) => {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', (data) => {
            strs[i] += data;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            ctr++;
            if(ctr == 3){
                console.log(strs[0]);
                console.log(strs[1]);
                console.log(strs[2]);
            }
        });
    });
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    httpGet(i);
}
```

The code works only by making it as a function. Why is this?

EDIT: 
the problem is that the "strs[i] += data" part doesn't work!

1. ACTUAL:    ""
2. EXPECTED:  "As cross as a turps how gutful of freckle. You little ripper gone walkabout mate you little ripper khe sanh. "
3. ACTUAL:    ""
4. EXPECTED:  "As dry as a milk bar when mad as a ambo. Stands out like a stickybeak my lets get some larrikin. He hasn't got a budgie smugglers and stands out like a show pony. "
5. ACTUAL:    ""
6. EXPECTED:  "You little ripper cockie where we're going digger. Grab us a bush oyster heaps you little ripper dero. Lets get some apples mate gutful of compo. "
7. ACTUAL:    ""
8. EXPECTED:  ""

Comment: What part doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why wrapping the async method in a function works better is because the passed on index `i` is the same as the expected index.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, 1000);
}
```

The output is always `3`, because the for loop finishes before the async method is done with the call.

You can however use the `let` keyword in es6 to keep blocked scope variables.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the http.get run the value of ' i ' is 2 in the loop ' for ' because it is the last value that ' i' has in loop. 
Instead in function the value is correct ' 0 ' ' 1'  and '2' because passing the ' i ' in function you have a local variable in function.

It is related to the closure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures